# "Разница в возрасте" или же "разница в возрастах"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Доброго времени всем!

Почему говорим **"*разница в возрасте*"**, а не **"разница в возрастах"**, хотя эта самая "разница" бывает только между двумя и более возрастами, то есть у нас фактически мн.ч. возраста, а стало быть и употребить мы должны вроде бы множественное число этого слова? То же самое и с выражением **"*разница во времени в Москве, в Киеве и в Алмате*"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему говорим "разница в возрасте", а не "разница в возрастах"

Сложный вопрос.

РАЗНИЦА **в чём:**

*в характерах, во вкусах, во взглядах, в привычках...*

*в возрасте, в положении, в образовании, во времени…*

Почему в одних случаях при сочетании со словом **разница** мы выбираем ед. число управляемого слова, а в других -- множественное?.. Наверное, в силу привычки.

Но бывает, говорят и *"разница в возрастах"*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот и мне начинает казаться, что мы, зачастую следуя непонятным традициям начинаем вводить в литературу неясно откуда взятые и далёкие от литературы галантрейщины.

Comment: «Галантрейщины»? Что это?

Comment: Простите, но там банальная и не простительная орфографическая ошибка. Не «галантрейщины», а галантерейщины. Это выражение моей любимой учительницы, ныне уже покойной Алиевой Маргариты Тимофеевны. Она порой так выражалась: "Русский язык -- говорила она -- достаточно богат и колоритен, чтоб обойтись без всяких матерных похабщин и неграмотных галантерейщин!"

Comment: Увы, я так и не смог найти более вразумительный ответ на свой вопрос, но всё таки отдам предпочтение Вашему ответу потому, что Вы были единственным, кто привёл пример прецедента.

Answer (score 2):

Разное управление падежами:

Разница **(чего?)** возрастов, характеров, взглядов, но: разница **(в чем)** в весе, в цене, в возрасте, во взглядах.

Разница (двух) **возрастов** - это разница двух величин (1) и (2).

Разница **в возрасте:** возраст (1) не равен возрасту (2).

Разница во взглядах: взгляды (1) не равны взглядам (2).

Comment: Вот и я об этом же, видите какая получается путаница: "**разница (в чем) в весе, в цене, в возрасте, во взглядах.**" Где-то мы употребляем ед.ч., а где-то, точь в точь в абсолютно такой же ситуации мы уже начинаем употреблять мн.ч.

Comment: Одна и та же ситуация  (одна семантика) описывается двумя грамматическим формами   (разные падежи, предложное и беспредложное управление и даже разное число), и это не путаница, это нормально в языке. Как выбрать правильную форму? Надо ее проверить на других примерах.  Например, разность (разница) чисел - Р.п. мн. числа, поэтому "разница возрастов".  Зададим вопрос: в чем разница между двумя предметами. Мы должны обозначить ПАРАМЕТР, а он обычно имеет форму ед. числа: вес, рост, возраст (редко мн. число: взгляды). Потому разница в возрасте (в параметре, по которому сравниваются предметы).

Comment: Улыбнули Ваши рассуждения! Но, увы и ах, они попахивают софизмом. Видите ли, когда речь идёт о возрастах двух лиц, то и об их разнице мы также должны говорить во множественном числе, так как мн.ч. в русском языке начинается с двух и более чисел... в отличии, скажем от арабского, где мн.ч. начинается с трёх и более.

Comment: Меня ваши рассуждения "улыбнули" также, особенно выражение "мы должны".  А  должны мы прежде всего соотносить свои взгляды со словарями и реальными текстами. Из толкового словаря:РАЗНИЦА, -ы; ж. 1. Несходство, различие в чём-л. Р. возрастов, характеров, взглядов. Р. в весе, в цене. Р. в возрасте, во вкусах, во времени.  Из Нацкорпуса: разница в ВОЗРАСТЕ (122 примера), разница в возрастах (1 пример). "С годами разница в возрасте между нами до такой степени сгладилась, что вскоре она стала относиться ко мне как к равной, как к подруге". [Т. Л. Сухотина-Толстая(.

Comment: **Меня ваши рассуждения "улыбнули" также, особенно выражение "мы должны"**

Коль Вы умудрились придраться к обычному, в идиоматическом смысле употреблённому, выражению "мы должны", ничем не обосновав свою придирку, разведя тут обычную демагогию, то я думаю нам дальше не о чём говорить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, со временем разобраться проще. Оно не имеет множественного числа, а слово "времена" означает несколько другое. В одном из значений, например, оно мало чем отличается от слова "время". Например, *настали трудные времена =~ настало трудное время*.
Про возраст, кстати, можно сказать примерно то же.

Comment: На счёт понятия "времени" согласен, резонное рассуждение, очень верное...